# Does SKShapeNode still leak memory?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skshapenode

There is plenty of info about all the problems with SKShapeNode in iOS 7.

[Memory Leak in Sprite Kit Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22323189/memory-leak-in-sprite-kit-application)

http://sartak.org/2014/03/skshapenode-you-are-dead-to-me.html

Have all these issues actually been resolved in iOS 8? There aren't any posts later than August 2014 describing problems, but I wanted to make sure before I committed to SKShapeNode.

**Update:**

According to LearnCocos2D you probably shouldn't use SKShapeNode for serious games. However, from inferring from what I've been reading, and from my (brief) experience, SKShapeNode won't cause any memory headaches during casual use. I'm inclined to assume this is true, unless anyone has information to indicate otherwise?

Comment: I don't know but why not write a little test app and test it with Instruments and see what you get.

Comment: Well yes, it doesn't leak memory in my current (very simple) test case. There were a ton of disjoint and bizarre edge cases in which it used to leak memory though, so I figured it would be more effective to just poll our collective knowledge.

Comment: IMO SKShapeNode is primarily a node that helps devs to add debug drawing to their apps. For actual game graphics I can't recommend it, as it does not support batch drawing, it can have visual glitches. Better to write a custom shader.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on Stack Overflow. See ["Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: I don't understand why people are rushing to close this question as primarily opinion based. This is a fair question to be asked, and in no way is an opinion. SKShapeNode's were practically unusable in iOS 7 because of the bugs and poor performance. It would be great if someone could actually post an answer detailing whether these issues have been fixed in iOS 8. The pros and cons of sprite node vs shape node is an entirely different discussion.

Comment: I agree with Epic Byte opinion. We are in iOS 9.3 (Swift 2.2) awaiting for Swift 3.x, I hope SKShapeNode will be corrected in the future. The actual version is pratically unusable..

Comment: @EpicByte, While this question being opinion based is debatable, it's not on-topic, as the question is A) too broad (asking multiple questions) and B) is inherently not a complete question. Just like an answer is not an answer if required information is behind a link (i.e. link only). A question is not a question, and is thus off-topic, if information required by the question is not *in the question*. This question asks about a list of issues contained on another site. At an *absolute minimum*, for this question to be on-topic, that list **must** be in the question itself, not behind a link.

Comment: @Makyen Today this question is not really relevant anymore. I agree keep it closed.

Comment: I think the question is still valid because I'm using SpriteKit in iOS 11 and I still haven't found any answer to the warnings about it leaking memory - I'd really like to know. As @thekwiat says, memory leaks can be very context-dependent so it's important to know more detail on when they occurred and if a major problem has been fixed.